# Changing data field type after creation with EF codefirst

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I've created an MVC app with a simple form using the codefirst approach. It has an ID, title, and description, pretty straightforward.

It has automatically created me a nice 'create' form which is awesome. However, the description field is only a, input, I'd rather it be a textarea given this will likely house quite a bit of text. I know I can just change it on the form but it's also on the other forms created by EF, it would be great if there was a way this could be done automatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DataTypeAttribute` to specify the type of control to be displayed

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

When using `@Html.EditorFor()`, it will render a `textarea` rather than `<input type="text" .. />`

Comment: thanks for your help, VS is asking me to generate a new constant for datatype? Is there a package or something that handles it?

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using. And have included `using System.ComponentModel;`

Comment: .Net 4.5.2 so I'm guessing MVC 4 (Where can I tell?)

Comment: Yes, using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: That was strange, I removed the using `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` then re-added it and now it works. Thanks again